# stop background to be draggable on a button click

Tags: jquery

I have some code that when I press button the background in the div start to be draggable. I would like to do something like when I click on some else button  the background stop to be draggable and when again I press button the bg start to be draggable again.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
<script src="draggable_background.js"></script>

<style>     
div { width: 320px; height: 240px; display: inline-block; font-family: 
sans-serif; border: 2px solid #aaa;}
</style>

<body>
<div id="default" style="background:url('aaa.jpg')">default</div>

<br><br>
<button id="first"></button>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#first').click(function() {
  $('#default').backgroundDraggable();
  $('div').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        html = $this.html();
    $this.empty().append($('<p>').html(html))
  });
  });
});

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you are using this library https://github.com/kentor/jquery-draggable-background

To disable the draggable you can call

```
$('div').backgroundDraggable('disable');
```

to make the button toggle isDraggable, you can use variable isDraggable, and check whether to toggle drag or disable drag

here's the full example

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="draggable_background.js"></script>
</head>


<style>     
div { width: 320px; height: 240px; display: inline-block; font-family: 
sans-serif; border: 2px solid #aaa;}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="default" style="background:url('bg.jpg')">default</div>

    <br><br>
    <button id="first">DRAG</button>


    <script>
    //While in global context declare variable
    var isDraggable = false;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#first').click(function() {

            if (!isDraggable)
            {
                //Not Draggable, then make it draggable
                $('#default').backgroundDraggable();
                $('div').each(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var html = $this.html();
                    $this.empty().append($('<p>').html($this.html()));
                });
                isDraggable = true;
            } else
            {
                //Already draggable, then disable it
                $('#default').backgroundDraggable('disable');
                isDraggable = false;
            }

        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: some syntax error i dont know where. sorry just newbie in coding jquery

Comment: i've updated the answer, please try to copy paste it again, the wrong line is in the <scrpt src=............ section

Comment: ohh sorry, there's an error again, your codes really messy, i will get it soon

Comment: Thx. that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this
`<button id="second">Second</div>`
in jQuery

```
<script>
 $('#second').on('click',function(){
    $('#default').backgroundDraggable('destroy');
  });

 </script>
```